# Websockets docker-compose vs docker swarm

Tags: spring-boot, docker, websocket, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I built simple app using Spring Boot Websockets with React as a front end (STOMP + Sock.js). When I deploy an app with `docker-compose up` everything works fine and websocket connection is established but once I deploy an app in docker swarm I get the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://.../websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

What is causing this issue?

Edit 1:

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.2'

networks:
  ws-swarm-network:

services:
  ws-front:
    depends_on:
      - ws-back
    container_name: ws-front
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - ws-swarm-network
    image: docker_ws-front
  ws-back:
    restart: always
    image: ws-back
    environment:
      - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - ws-swarm-network
```

When deploying in docker swarm mode i use:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192....
```

and

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml stackname
```

Comment: Hi mate, I feel having a snippet of the code you have server side and client side you help. Just the necessary part to help us debug.

Comment: Also your docker compose and docker swarm networking setting would help.

Comment: @Paulo I have added the only docker information I use

Comment: What URL do you use to connect? `ws://ws-back:8080/websocket`?

Comment: @slauth This is my socket connection string: `socket = new SockJS('http://' + window.location.hostname + ':8080/ws');`

Comment: @Aline137 and `window.location.hostname` resolves to `localhost`? Or how are you accessing the frontend?